# Netbeans search color, how to customize?

Tags: netbeans, colors, editor

I've been using NB for many years, but always find it hard to customize the editor's color, now the color in the "Find" drop-down box is hard to see, can someone point me in the right direction to change it ? In the attached picture you can see the selected text is hard to read, I need to change the foreground color to white, where should I make this change ?[image]

On this note, I'd like to suggest an improvement on this function, won't it be nice and easy to just right click on the area you want to customize color and a drop-down menu will help you choose the things you want to change, color should be one of them, instead of going through : Tools -> Options -> who-knows-where to find the item !

Answer (score 0):

The colors in the "Find" textfield are the same as the selected text colors.

So you can try to change the foreground and background colors used when you select some text.

Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Highlighting -> Selected Text

Comment: No, it's definitely different, my selected foreground is silver and background is dark blue, as you can see, in the "Find" area, the selected foreground is not silver.

Comment: That's why I suggested use right mouse click to drop down a menu with color change as an option, so user can do it right where he needs it. Instead of trying to guess the path of who-knows-where !